# How to make a drag bar to change the vertical height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a 100% height div be divided by a dragging border vertically. Here is a fiddle of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/k5rtbzs5/

The HTML is:

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="top">
      test
  </div>

    <div class="slider"></div>

  <div class="bot">
      test
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

.column {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid #000;
}

.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #989898;
}

.bot {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #686868;
}

.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

How can I make the div="slider" be able to change the height of div="top" and div="bot" by dragging it? I am also trying to keep the div="column" the full height of the browser window.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mousemove event to change the height of top and bottom divs using jquery.
Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').on('mousedown',function(e){
    $('.column').on('mousemove',function(e){
        diff = $('.slider').offset().top + 5 - e.pageY ;
        $('.top').height($('.top').height()-diff);
        $('.bot').height($('.bot').height()+diff);
    });
  });
  $('.column').on('mouseup',function(){
      $('.column').off('mousemove');
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/ndud4ff7/) http://jsfiddle.net/ndud4ff7/